# inserting css based on some condition in a page

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page which can behave as a pop up in sharepoint..Now I can using this javascript to identify if it is a pop up if (`window.location.search.match("[?&]IsDlg=1")`) but what I am not able to figure out is how do I insert some css based on if this condition is true.

One way I am thinking is to have a label in the page and then use code behind to identify the condition and insert the css but I also want to check whether this is possible though javascript.Can someone please guide me .

I think I can do something with jQuery like this

```
$('<style type="text/css">#foo { background: #000; } </style>').appendTo("head");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question, perhaps you can show some code?
Using jQuery you can set css like so:

```
$('.my-div').css('display','block');
```

Or you can just write the css and put it in your stylesheet and then set classes on your elements like so:

```
$('.my-div').addClass('yellow-border');
```

Comment: Sorry should had give some more details..So I have a page which has can be opened like a regular page or as a pop up..what I want is that when it's opened as a pop there should be some css inserted in the page ..now the way I was thinking is that I can check for the condition that the page is pop up or not but then how do I insert the css.

Comment: Sounds like if you can check that it is a popup, you can add a class to the top of your element hierarchy like so: http://jsfiddle.net/tfZwU/2/

Comment: This is what I am doing . <body onload="javascript:test()"> firing this function on page load and then doing this .Seems to be working fine .Do you guys think it's a nice or something better
      function test()
      {
          if (window.location.search.match("[?&]IsDlg=1"))
          {
              $('<style type="text/css">#foo { background: #000; } </style>').appendTo("head");

          }     

      }

Comment: Actually I can just use this  $(document).ready(function () {
          if (true) {
              $('<style type="text/css">#foo { background: blue; } </style>').appendTo("head");

          }
      });

Comment: That should work fine, adding a class as in my second example would probably be better performance wise, but if all you need is 1 color then go with it :)